# docker-compose not pulling images if the corresponding service has a build context section

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble getting `docker-compose pull` to actually pull everything in my docker-compose.yml file.

It looks something like this. . .

```
services:
  my_Service1:
    image1: path-to-image.com/this_image:v0
    build:
      context: ./dir1/nesteddir/yetanothernesteddir
  my_Service2:
    image1: path-to-image.com/that_image:v0
    build:
      context: ./dir2/nesteddir/yetanothernesteddir
  my_Service1:
    image1: path-to-image.com/my_image:v0
    build:
      context: ./dir3/nesteddir/yetanothernesteddir
```

Specifically though, I have noticed that it will only pull the images without the build context section. However, if it has a build: context: section, it skips it.

In one yml file in particular, I only have services with build contexts, and so when I run the command, it does nothing. No output at all.

I am sure that I am connected to the repo as well as I am able to docker pull from the routes just fine.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: In case it matters, I am pulling from a private nexus repo.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `build`, `image` refers to the name of the image that it's going to be built.

Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

Comment: What do you mean? Does putting the image like I have not specify docker-compose pull to pull an image from that repo?

Comment: @CalebRenfroe `image` (which by the way, you have `image1`, I assume it's a typo in the question), pulls the image when there is no `build`. As you have `build` , the image is built at runtime or by `docker-compose build`, but it's not pulled from anywhere. In this case, as specified in the documentation I linked, `image` just refers to the name of the image that is going to be built.

Comment: Oh wow. That's ridiculous!
I have been wondering why the image is not pulled like FOR YEARS!

How can I avoid constructing image name myself and writing `docker pull...` (which will obviously work )in such a case?